# Laravel - listening for specific Asterisk events using Marcelog Pami

Tags: laravel, asterisk, voip, asteriskami

I'm building application in `Laravel 8`. In application I need to receive event from `Asterisk`. To do that I downloaded [Pami](https://marcelog.github.io/articles/pami_introduction_tutorial_how_to_install.html) package.
In app\Listeners folder I created file `AmiTestListener.php` for listener (code I copied from [Marcelog Pami](https://marcelog.github.io/articles/pami_introduction_tutorial_how_to_install.html) website):

```
<?php
use PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl as PamiClient;
use PAMI\Message\Event\EventMessage;
use PAMI\Listener\IEventListener;

$pamiClientOptions = array(
    'host' => '85.34.56.189',
    'scheme' => 'tcp://',
    'port' => 5045,
    'username' => 'admin',
    'secret' => 'mysecret',
    'connect_timeout' => 10000,
    'read_timeout' => 10000
);

$pamiClient = new PamiClient($pamiClientOptions);

// Open the connection
$pamiClient->open();

$pamiClient->registerEventListener(function (EventMessage $event) {
    var_dump($event);
});

$running = true;

// Main loop
while($running) {
    $pamiClient->process();
    usleep(1000);
}

// Close the connection
$pamiClient->close();
```

Connection with `FreePbx` on given address works. I can connect. But I can't receive any event.
Above listener I registered in `app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php`:

```
use App\Listeners\AmiTestNotification;
use App\Listeners\AmiTestListener;
use App\Events\AmiTestProcessed;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
            AmiTestListener::class
        ]
    ];
```

When I call using my mobile phone to `FreePbox`, connection with Jitsi application is established and I can talk with my mobile phone and Jitsi. But I can't receive any event from FreePbx.

Answer (score -1):

This question have no any relation to laravel.

You have read doc for PamiClient package or it source code.

For get events you have enable events after connected via AMI protocol. Client may not support event at all, but it is opensource so should be no problem to add that.